# Cannot reach Traefik dashboard, get a 404. Installed on Kubernetes (k3d) from Helm chart (on Ubuntu 20.04 Laptop)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, traefik, traefik-ingress, k3s

I created a k3d cluster like this:

```sh
# Create 3 server nodes and only allow control plane stuff on there (and things with tolerations)
# Pretty print:
# k3d cluster create dev 
#   --api-port 6551 
#   --port "8081:80@loadbalancer" 
#   --servers 3 
#   --k3s-server-arg --node-taint="CriticalAddonsOnly=true:NoExecute" 
#   --k3s-server-arg "--no-deploy=traefik"
#
k3d cluster create dev --api-port 6551 --port "8081:80@loadbalancer" --servers 3 --k3s-server-arg --node-taint="CriticalAddonsOnly=true:NoExecute" --k3s-server-arg "--no-deploy=traefik"
```

Then I installed Traefik:

```sh
# Has tolerations so it can run on those nodes
# Pretty print:
# helm install traefik traefik/traefik 
#   --set tolerations[0].key=CriticalAddonsOnly 
#   --set tolerations[0].operator=Exists 
#   --set tolerations[0].effect=NoExecute 
#   --set ingressRoute.dashboard.annotations."kubernetes\.io/ingress\.class"=traefik-internal
#
helm install traefik traefik/traefik --set tolerations[0].key=CriticalAddonsOnly --set tolerations[0].operator=Exists --set tolerations[0].effect=NoExecute --set ingressRoute.dashboard.annotations."kubernetes\.io/ingress\.class"=traefik-internal
```

Then I started port forwarding:

```sh
kubectl port-forward $(kubectl get pods --selector "app.kubernetes.io/name=traefik" --output=name) 9000:9000
```

When I visit `http://127.0.0.1/dashboard/` I get a 404.

I can see the pods:

```sh
kubectl get pods

# NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
# svclb-traefik-5gbwz        2/2     Running   0          20m
# svclb-traefik-fmpgc        2/2     Running   0          20m
# svclb-traefik-lg9j6        2/2     Running   0          20m
# traefik-84846f6fcb-q5hwd   1/1     Running   0          20m
```

However, no ingresses show:

```sh
kubectl get ingresses --all-namespaces
# Warning: extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.14+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
# No resources found
```

The Kubernetes version is `1.19.4`
What setting is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is two things:

1. The `Service` and other K8s objects installed via Traefik's Helm chart that aren't in the `Deployment` do not have sections to pull in the `tolerations` from the `values.yaml`
2. I only had tainted nodes running, so the Traefik Deployment installed its pods, but nothing else was scheduled

**The Fix**

```sh
# Install worker nodes that aren't tainted
k3d node create worker --cluster dev --replicas 3
```

*After* that, you can install Traefik.